# SCSS @for loop - Possible to not from from and to?

Tags: css, sass

My code below increases the animation delay on each `.element` but I have to state the number (1-6). Is there a way to not dictate a number as I want to dynamically create more elements via JS?

```
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  .element:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: (#{$i * 0.175}s); 
  }
}
```

Comment: SASS/SCSS has no knowledge of the DOM or what JS does - it compiles down to CSS which likewise has no knowledge.

Comment: It would be great if CSS allowed `.element{ counter-increment: foo; animation-delay: calc(counter(foo)*0.175)s; }`. Maybe in 6 to 8 trienniums?

Comment: It sure would. I am having to guess of a number that I don't think will be reached.